# Regex for replacing anything other than characters, more than one spaces and number only in end with empty char

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I want to replace anything other than character, spaces and number only in end with empty string or in other words: we replace any number or spaces comes in-starting or in-middle of the string replace with empty string.

**Example**

```
**Input**    **Output**
Ndd12    Ndd12
12Ndd12  Ndd12
Ndd   12  Ndd 12
Nav  G45up Nav Gup
```

**Attempted Code**

```
regexp_replace(df1[col_name]), "(^[A-Za-z]+[0-9 ])", ""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\d+|(?<=\w)\d+(?![\d\s])|(?<=\s)\s+|(?<=\w)\W|\W(?=\w)|(?<!\w)\W|\W(?!\w)
```

Comment: Please add some explanations - why is this code working?

Comment: It will remove all the special character from name column and keep the number only in the end.

Comment: Add this to your answer :)

Comment: I'm curious about what you do after the match to get the expected output.

Comment: Data Standardization and data validation

Answer (score 2):

if you use `python`, you can use regular expressions.
You can use the `re` module.

```py
import re

new_string = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]","",s)
```

Where `^` means exclusion.

Regular expressions exist in other languages. So it would be helpful to find a regular expression.

Comment: I want numbers in the end of the string only. If any number comes in-starting and in-middle then replace with empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```sh
\d+(?!\d*$)|[^\w\n]+(?!([A-Z]|$))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZrgtb/6)

**Explanation:**

- `\d+(?!\d*$)`: Match 1+ digits that are not followed by 0+ digits and end of line
- `|`: OR
- `[^\w\n]+(?!([A-Z]|$))`: Match 1+ non-word characters that are not followed by an uppercase letter or and end of line

Comment: I have one more use case here. suppose Name is "Mr Nave12en so the output will be "Mr Naveen".

Comment: @Naveen: Please don't change requirement from comment section after answer has been posted on originally written problem.

Comment: I just got this use case now. Sorry for the change in comment section. Let me add that use case as well in question.

Comment: I have tried the updated answer from you but it is removing all the space in-middle as well.

Comment: What kind of question is that? You keep adding requirements in comments but don't have clear requirements written in question.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this regex to capture all characters that you want to remove from the string.

```
^\d+|(?<=\w)\d+(?![\d\s])|(?<=\s)\s+
```

Do

```py
regexp_replace(df1[col_name]), "^\d+|(?<=\w)\d+(?![\d\s])|(?<=\s)\s+", ""))
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a3ToxU/1)

Explanation:

`^\d+` - captures all digits in a sequence from the start.

`(?<=\w)\d+(?![\d\s])` - Positive look behind for a word character with a negative look ahead for a number followed by space and capturing a sequence of digits in the middle. (Captures digits in `G45up`)

`(?<=\s)\s+` - positive look behind for a space followed by one or more spaces, capturing all additional spaces.

**Note** : This regex could be inefficient when matching large strings as it uses expensive look-arounds.

Comment: It is not removing $ and other symbol in between the name.

Comment: I am getting this output : ag$arwal.... $ is coming in name

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. Please don't come up with new questions from time to time on the same post. The answer is to the question you posted. Please ask a new question for anything different. Anyway you can fix that with `^\d+|(?<=\w)(\d+|\$)(?![\d\s])|(?<=\s)\s+`

Comment: It is not matching `N dd 12`

Comment: @anubhava Yes as It's not in the requirements specified by PO. Not even in the comments.